# example using uploadDirectory from android to S3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Will someone please provide an example for uploading a bunch of photos to S3 using `uploadDirectory`? Say I have 300 photos in a directory named “special_photos” on my android device. And I want to upload all of these photos to Amazon S3. I figure `uploadDirectory` may be the best method for doing this. But being new to Amazon cloud, I don’t know how I might do it. All I have gleaned so far is that the method executes asynchronously and so can be called from the main thread. I keep finding php codes on the internet. But I don’t use PHP. Does anyone have a complete working example they don’t mind sharing with the community? I am using the SDK via gradle on Android Studio. Also, is there some kind of callback for knowing when all the photos have been uploaded? Say for instance I want to delete the photos and the directory once they have been uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `uploadDirectory` but there is [Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm). This will do your large data upload to S3. As stated [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), the Multipart Upload Docs say:

> Using the list multipart uploads operation, you can obtain a list of multipart uploads in progress. An in-progress multipart upload is an upload that you have initiated, but have not yet completed or aborted. Each request returns at most 1000 multipart uploads. If there are more than 1000 multipart uploads in progress, you need to send additional requests to retrieve the remaining multipart uploads.

To address the callback, there is a completion called once all of the `TransferUtility` items are uploaded. This [open source](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KF0YUQITA164/AWS-SDK-for-Android-Transfer-Manager-to-Transfer-Utility-Migration-Guide) adds listeners applied to the upload function. I would recommend breaking up your calls to 30 at a time, then delete the corresponding photos - in case there is a failure with the upload. There is a success and fail return, so obviously only delete in case of success.

[HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuJava.html) is the AWS documentation for Android Multipart Uploads

[HERE](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KF0YUQITA164/AWS-SDK-for-Android-Transfer-Manager-to-Transfer-Utility-Migration-Guide) is an article that will help migrate & understand the differences between `TransferManager` and `TransferUtility`

[HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-retrieve-s3-transferutility.html) is a good article on getting started with the Android `TransferManager`

And [HERE](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample) is an open source demo - under the `S3_TransferManager`

Hope this helps!

#### Update:

The below code is all taken from @awslabs references

**Create client:**

```
public static AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
    if (sS3Client == null) {
        sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context.getApplicationContext()));
    }
    return sS3Client;
}
```

**Create TransferUtility:**

```
public static TransferUtility getTransferUtility(Context context) {
    if (sTransferUtility == null) {
        sTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(getS3Client(context.getApplicationContext()),
                context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sTransferUtility;
}
```

**Use TransferUtility to get all upload transfers:**

```
observers = transferUtility.getTransfersWithType(TransferType.UPLOAD);
```

**Add your records:** - you could iterate over the file names in your directory

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Util.fillMap(map, observer, false);
transferRecordMaps.add(map);
```

**This starts everything:**

```
private void beginUpload(String filePath) {
    if (filePath == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not find the filepath of the selected file",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    File file = new File(filePath);
    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(),
            file);
    observers.add(observer);
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Util.fillMap(map, observer, false);
    transferRecordMaps.add(map);
    observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener());
    simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**This is your completion:**

```
private class GetFileListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // The list of objects we find in the S3 bucket
    private List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjList;
    // A dialog to let the user know we are retrieving the files
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadSelectionActivity.this,
                getString(R.string.refreshing),
                getString(R.string.please_wait));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... inputs) {
        // Queries files in the bucket from S3.
        s3ObjList = s3.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME).getObjectSummaries();
        transferRecordMaps.clear();
        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : s3ObjList) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("key", summary.getKey());
            transferRecordMaps.add(map);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will look into the links you provide. I saw uploadDirectory at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File,%20boolean)

Comment: Ahh! Yes, this is part of the `TransferManager`. Let me search for an exact example

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question: I see that TransferManger is deprecated and is superseded by TransferUtility. I am guessing the same claims apply. Is that correct?

Comment: It's all sort of the same. AWS made quite a few name changes in the recent month. I will update the answer momentarily with the non-depreciated docs.

Comment: Are you saying that in `TransferObserver upload(String bucket, String key, File file)` the **File** specified can in fact be a Directory and that all the image files inside that directory will be uploaded?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. The truth is I had already looked at the links you provided before asking the question. I looked at them all the same to see if I missed something. But I am still not getting in. You got a lot of up votes which must mean your answer is good. It's just not gotten me any closer.

Comment: I believe you want to make a `TransferObserver` for each file in the directory. So recursively go over each file and add a `TransferObserver`.

So lets say you take a `List` of all the objects in the directory. You can:

 - Take ten of them
 - Shoot of an upload
 - Delete locally
 - Then on complete, send off the next ten photos

Comment: Not a problem. What kinds of debug results are you getting? Add some code you have, results you're getting, and particularly the debug stuff you're getting. That almost always tells whats going on.

And no worries if it's not answered, its not answered!

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: You got it! All of it is just in the docs. Sometimes hard to find exactly what you're trying to do in all the .md's and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a List to your service that is using TransferUtility to upload multiple images. At least that is how I was able to make it work.